# Read NSUserdefaults into NSArray

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults

I am trying to read the values of Root.plist key into NSArray so I can populate a table view for my App settings.

I am using the following code to retrieve the values of the key "country":

```
NSArray *arrayCountry = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] arrayForKey:@"country"];
NSLog(@"Number of items in array >>>>>> %d", arrayCountry.count);
```

NSLog returns:

> Number of items in array >>>>>> 0

I tried the same on different keys but still get the same result.

Can anyone shed some light on this issue.  Did I miss anything here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your `arrayCountry` isn't `nil`.  If it is, `arrayCountry.count` will return zero even if it is nil.

Try this:

```
NSUserDefaults* std = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[std setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"US",@"GB",@"CN",nil] forKey:@"country"];
NSArray *arrayCountry = [std arrayForKey:@"country"];
if(arrayCountry == nil){
    NSLog(@"Something's strange in the neighborhood.");
}else{
    NSLog(@"Number of items in array >>>>>> %d", arrayCountry.count);
}
```

Comment: Note that making an instance of `standardUserDefaults` is nothing but a convenience for less typing - it would work if you replaced `std` everywhere with `[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]` too

Comment: Thanks Tim, your code will work if you add ", nil" after @"CN". in my case I created the key in Xcode and trying to read in code, and confirmed that it have items added but not sure why it returns nil,0 when I read in the code

Comment: Fixed, thanks for the catch.  I was just trying to make a basic array in a hurry.